# I can't check the empty or null when I click submit

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-ui-router, node-modules

---

I can't check the empty or null when I click submit.

When pressing the spacebar, the empty value will be sent to the database.

button can submit pass to sent data to database

### Please help.

```html
  <form #Register="ngForm">
  <div style="width: 500px">

    <br/>
    <h4>New Reegister</h4>
    <br/>

    <div class="form-group">
      <dt><label for="name">Name</label></dt>
      <input [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input your name" data-bv-notempty-message="The name is required" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <dt><label for="lastname">LastName</label></dt>
      <input [(ngModel)]="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input your lastname" data-bv-notempty-message="The lastname is required" required>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <dt><label for="email2">E-mail</label></dt>
      <input [(ngModel)]="email2" name="email2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input your email" data-bv-notempty-message="email" required [pattern]="emailRegex" >
      <div class= "p-2 text-danger"> <small>* Require Example : xxxxx@gmail.com</small> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <dt><label for="password2">Password</label></dt>
      <input [(ngModel)]="password2" name="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="input your password" minlength="4" required>
      <div class= "p-2 text-danger"> <small>* Enter atleast 4 characters</small> </div>
    </div>
  <!--
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password3">Password Confirm</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="password3" name="password3" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="input your password" required>
    </div>
    -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <dt><label for="passwordhint">Password Hint</label></dt>
        <input [(ngModel)]="passwordhint" name="passwordhint" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="input your password" minlength="4" required>
        <div class= "p-2 text-danger"> <small>* Enter atleast 4 characters</small> </div>
      </div>

    <button type="submit" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" [disabled]="!Register.valid" (click)="Regis()">Save</button>
    

  </div>
  </form>
```

---

**cannot check data null**

When pressing the spacebar, the empty value will be sent to the database.

button can submit pass to sent data to database

### Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data " " is a valid data but it's empty, not null. You can make a check by `trim` function before saving it into database.

For example:

```js
let str = ' ';
console.log(str.length) // Length = 1
str = str.trim();
// Here str = '' and you can check length of it
console.log(str.length) // Length = 0
```

More detail: [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: thank you , if i want check "" Not to press Submit , Please bother you to recommend

Comment: You can add a handle function in js for `onChange` event of your inputs (email...)  and trim the value that user enters, every time they change it. If input values are null or empty, you will disable Submit button, user can only click on Submit when all input values is valid (that time you enable Submit button)

Answer (score 1):

This has to go in the submit button.

In this case if the variable 'name' contain only spaces the function 'trim' will reduce its length to 0.

So the database call will happen only if the variable 'name' has a value.

```
this.name = this.name.trim();
if(name.length) {
    // do the database call
} else {
    // prompt a message to let the user know that the particular field is empty
}
```